# GNU Make ignore all rules except first

Tags: c, gnu-make

I have a project with a bunch of source file, some of them (but not all) must be rebuilded after one specific *.h file is changed (currtype.h). I have explicit rule for this in my makefile:

```
%.obj: %.c
    $(COMPILE)

main.obj: main.c currtype.h
    $(COMPILE)
CustomHTTPApp.obj: CustomHTTPApp.c currtype.h
    $(COMPILE)
CustomSNMPApp.obj: CustomSNMPApp.c currtype.h
    $(COMPILE)

COMPILE = -"$(CC)" -C $< $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_STACK)
```

But than I change my currtype.h I see only main.c being recompiled. If I put CustomHTTPApp on the first line and main.c on second, then only CustomHTTPApp is recompiled etc. How this can be fixed?

Comment: Could you please provide your command line when invoking `make`? Also the platform and which `make` it is?

Comment: I just type make in my MinGW-w64 Win64 Shell (I'm running Windows 8.1).

Comment: BTW despite this dependecy check problem, project is building properly.

Comment: mingw, dependency problems, Windows 8.1, doesn't sound good...

Comment: @Keroronsk Alright, so far so good. Why do you have a dash (`-`) in front of `"$(CC)"`? This completely trips my attempts to test your makefile.

Comment: @amn I guess I just copy-pasted it from manual, or something. Project building without it too (just checked).

Comment: Here is my complete  makefile: https://paste.ee/p/wZhS8

Comment: `make` only considers the first found rule when invoked without expliti target(s). If you want it to consider all your rules, move `all: ...` so that it is the first rule `make` finds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just run "make", the first non-implicit rule gets executed, which just builds main.obj. You need to add another target building all output files, e.g. called "all":

```
all: main.obj CustomHTTPApp.obj CustomSNMPApp.obj

%.obj: %.c
    $(COMPILE)

main.obj: main.c currtype.h
    $(COMPILE)
CustomHTTPApp.obj: CustomHTTPApp.c currtype.h
    $(COMPILE)
CustomSNMPApp.obj: CustomSNMPApp.c currtype.h
    $(COMPILE)

COMPILE = "$(CC)" -C $< $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_STACK)
```

Comment: Thank you, now it makes sense. I guess the case is closed now.